# complexification of real vector bundles on $S^4$ and $S^8$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory

Prove there is a surjection $\tilde{KO}(S^8) \to \tilde{K}(S^8)$.(similarly for $S^4$)

My idea:

It is equivalent to show in every class of complex vector bundles on $S^8(S^4)$, there is a representative that is the complexification of a real vector bundle.

It can be proved that when a (complex) vector bundle E is equipped with a conjugate linear isomorphism $J$ that satisfies $J^2=-1$, then E is the complexification of a real vector bundle.

How do I go from here? I cannot construct such $J$ explicitly in both cases.

Comment: Do you know the values of these $K$ and $KO$-groups? What are $\widetilde{KO}(S^8)$ and $\widetilde{K}(S^8)$?

Comment: @ kamills Are they both $\mathbb{Z}$ by Bott periodity? So do you mean only need to find one maps to 1?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. By Bott periodicity your problem for $S^8$ reduces to the claim that there's a map $\widetilde{KO}(S^0) \to \widetilde{K}(S^0)$ that's surjective. Perhaps you can figure out what that map is (you can construct it on the level of vector bundles).